# Get the values of textbox having same Id in a table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table class="csstable">
    <tr>
       <td>
       <textarea id="txtOption" rows="2" cols="30">hi this is me!!!</textarea>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>
       <textarea id="txtOption" rows="2" cols="30">hi this is you!!!</textarea>
       </td>
    </tr>
```

What i did:

```
  $(".csstable").each(function(){
       alert($("#txtOption").val());
      });
```

I am getting the first value of text area at both time ie.**hi this is me!!!**

Comment: `ID` should be unique.

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with the same id. It violates the guidelines set by the W3C.

Comment: @thatidiotguy More importantly, the DOM parser and JavaScript engine will never find the second instance of a given ID. They assume IDs are unique and stop looking after finding the first one.

Comment: @Blazemonger they will, but they have to _expect_ multiple instances. jQuery with an ID selector doesn't.

Comment: @JanDvorak Really? I'd like to see an example of that.

Comment: @Blazemonger here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/tWsHL/

Comment: @JanDvorak Interesting trick, although as you point out yourself, that's not exactly the same thing. Even so, I would consider this a bug in jQuery's Sizzle selector engine.

Comment: @Blazemonger jQuery only uses Sizzle as a replacement for querySelectorAll. This is a jQuery thing: if the selector matches `^\#\w+$` and there is no context, use `getElementById`. You can see how strict the condition is: http://jsfiddle.net/tWsHL/2/ . `*#id` is not an ID selector either (according to jQuery).

Comment: @Blazemonger I actually used it once (either that, or rewrite a big chunk of code just because that piece of HTML is actually on the page twice for a split second).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two id's with the same value on a page, that is invalid.

ID must be unique.

Try using a class (or something else) to select instead

```
<textarea class="txtoption1" rows="2" cols="30">option1</textarea>

<textarea class="txtoption2" rows="2" cols="30">option2</textarea>
```

Comment: I am dynamically creating these textareas, so i can make the ID of these textareas unique like textOption1,textOption2 but class i can,t change each time.  then how to get the text of these dynamically generated textareas???

Answer (score 1):

When you have more than one element with the same id you will only match the first element.

So, use `class` instead, get it by tag name or use unique ids.

Then you can get it's value by the following.

```
$(".csstable .myTextareaClass").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

or

```
$(".csstable textarea").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

or

```
alert($('#textareaId').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Each id must be **unique** it's called `id` for a reason.

Instead you should use `class` attribute

```
<textarea class="txtOption" rows="2" cols="30">hi this is you!!!</textarea>
```

You can read more about it **[here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp)**